# Fluent Nhibernate 1.0 - Specify foreign key constraint name between class and joined subclass

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-key-relationship, joined-subclass

I think this should be simple, but I can't figure out how to do it.  Suppose I have the following maps:

```
public class AnimalMap : ClassMap<Animal> { Id( x => x.Id); }

public class CatMap: SubclassMap<Cat> {
    Extends<AnimalMap>();
    Map(x => x.IsDomestic);
}
```

Which creates tables as I expect:

```
Animal
------
Id

Cat
----
AnimalId : FK to Animal (named FK3500ABA0D)
IsDomestic
```

As noted, the FK gets generated by the db and ends up as FK3500ABA0D.  All I want to do is set the name of that constraint, but I can't find how to do it via Fluent NHibernate (or actually even plain NHibernate, for that matter).

So, what am I missing?

Comment: FNH 1.0 did not have the ability to name FKs.  My accepted answer pertains to that version, but later versions should see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if FluentNH supports it, but the XML is simple:

```
<joined-subclass name="Cat">
  <key column="AnimalId" foreign-key="NameOfTheFK"/>
</joined-subclass>
```

Answer (score 22):

Fluent NH does allow this:

```
public class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention{
     public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance) {
          instance.ForeignKey(string.Format("FK_{0}_{1}",
               instance.EntityType.Name,
               instance.Name));
     }
}
```

You'd also need to implement `IHasManyConvention` and `IHasManyToManyConvention` in the same way as above.

Comment: FYI, at the time the question was asked and answer that feature was not in FNH.  I've updated the question and left a comment explaining why the accepted answer is not being changed.  Thanks for your answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the following works well for me:

```
public class JoinedSubclassForeignKeyConvention : IJoinedSubclassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IJoinedSubclassInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Type.BaseType != null)
            instance.Key.ForeignKey(string.Format("FK_{0}_{1}", instance.EntityType.Name, instance.Type.BaseType.Name));
    }
}
```

Your foreign key constraint would then be named as FK_Cat_Animal

Comment: Did this work with FNH 1.0 however?  Later versions fixed the issue, but this question is about 1.0 specifically.